# Can I use WordPress blog as a subfolder of my main domain with a https NGINX?

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, meteor, https

I am developing a plateform on node/meteorjs stack  and I want to add a WordPress blog for our website as well.

> https//www.XXXXXX.com     --> go to meteor app
>
> https//www.XXXXXX.com/blog   --> go to blog

I've got a NGINX front with https certificate

My NGINX config is :
`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name XXXX.ovh;
    return 301 https://XXXX.ovh$request_uri;
}

upstream meteorapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream blog {
    server 52.16.157.100;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.XXXX.ovh;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name XXXX.ovh;
    return 301 https://www.XXXX.ovh$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    root /var/www/html;

    server_name www.XXXX.ovh;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXX.ovh/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXXX.ovh/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

     location /blog {
            proxy_pass http://blog;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location /wp-content {
            proxy_pass http://blog;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /wp-admin {
            proxy_pass http://blog;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://meteorapp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

My blog is hosted on other server and my meteor is in a docker container.

With this configuration, css and image of my blog doesn't work (i try to access the http ressources...

so I got some errors as :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.cdispo.ovh/blog' was loaded over
HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.XXXX.ovh/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/assets/images/header.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

how can I do ?

Comment: It looks like your blog is in `http`. Look at your `nginx` configuration in the `blog` server and also check `wordpress` configuration (admin panel) to check if the `site_url` is set with `https`

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use a subdomain in this manner "blog.myapp.com". Otherwise if the Meteor app controls the root ie "myapp.com" you will need to redirect all requests coming in to "myapp.com/blog" in your router.